# Is it possible to omit a punctuation in a poster?

Tags: meaning, grammar, punctuation

Is it possible to omit punctuation in a poster?
The poster I am working with consists of text: "Yes, you can! Yes, you did!".

This poster is motivational. It dedicated to one particular person and symbolized the self-competence of the person.

This text will be placed in two blocks, separated by asterisks symbol:

[image]

The two text boxes represent two periods of time:

- the top box represents the moment of time when the person not sure about the possibility of achieving the expected results;
- the bottom text box represents the moment when all the objectives realized successfully, and
- the asterisk symbol represents a period between two events.

The motivational message of the poster is: "Yes, maybe you not fully realize how you achieve the objective, you afraid of the complexity and ambiguity but after the period of a certain time, you will overview the results, and you will be amazed by the results obtained!"

Is it possible to omit punctuation is this particular case without a loss of meaning?

Comment: Depends on what it means, doesn't it?

Comment: You would lose the emphasis of the exclamation point if you left it off, but that could possibly be made up for by the all-caps.  The comma I think (depending on context) doesn't take much away from the meaning by being absent.

Comment: Is it some sort of motivational poster, the message being you can do something and you will do it? Is there a picture or graphic? It seems fairly reasonable and comprehensible based on your description, but you're always best doing a mock-up and asking people what they think.

Comment: This instance is fine, but beware situations where punctuation changes the meaning. Do not make a poster that asks "Do you like cooking, dogs, and children?" into a poster that asks "Do you like cooking dogs and children?".